# How to convert a list of symbols to strings and then split by a delimiter

Tags: kdb

Say I have a list of symbols like so...

```
q) list
`hello_world.q
`hello_world_2.q
```

I'd like to split this so I end up with this list of strings...

```
q) new_list
"hello_world"
"hello_world_2"
```

how is that done?

I can do this using something like...

```
string1: "`" vs string list[0]
string1: "." vs string1[1]
```

But not sure how to do the full list

Comment: Something like: const new_list = list.map(str => str.replace(/^`/, '').replace(/\.q$/, ''));

Comment: hi thanks but i don't think that's q syntax?

Comment: Oh sorry haha! I do not know why I thought I am answering a JS question. My bad!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `vs`, `each` and each right (`/:`):

```
q)string first each` vs/:`hello_world.q`hello_world_2.q
"hello_world"
"hello_world_2"
```

Use case of `vs` is documented here: https://code.kx.com/q/ref/vs/#symbol-by-dot

Comment: Got it! To be exact, i mean the list so... `names: string first each` vs/:list`

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively:

```html
q)string(` vs'`hello_world.q`hello_world_2.q)[;0]
"hello_world"
"hello_world_2"
```